# Token-Based File Processing

Tags: java, file

I can't seem to figure out how to code this. I am still fairly new to Java and I've gone over all the PowerPoints and notes I have.

Write a static method named boyGirl that takes a string of text as a parameter.  Assume that the text represents a series of names followed by integers, and that the names alternate between boys' names and girls names.  Your method should compute the sum of the boys' integers and the sum of the girls' integers separately and print them.  The line could end with either a boy or girl; you may not assume that it contains an even number of names.  For example, if the String contains the following text,

```
"JP 3 Helene 7 Jordan 14 Iva 13 Sergey 4 Marianne 9 Kenneth 6"
```

then your method should produce the following output:

```
4 boys, 3 girls
Boys sum  = 26
Girls sum = 29
```

Comment: Could you post some code that you have tried that has not worked for you?

Comment: honestly im really confused on just how to answer. i know the names alternate between boy and girl. my problem is separating the integers from the strings. i havent come up with any useful code to help unfortunately. im still trying though.

Comment: Check out the String.split() function. [The API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) is your best friend.

Comment: Try writing code for a simpler problem. Like just add up a list of integers in a string and print the sum. Then put in the names, then the alternation between boys and girls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't judge me. I'm young and I need the reputation :)

```
package jfd;

public class BoyGirlCounter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        countBoyGirlInts("JP 3 Helene 7 Jordan 14 Iva 13 Sergey 4 Marianne 9 Kenneth 6");
    }

    public static void countBoyGirlInts(String boysgirls) {
        String[] words = boysgirls.split(" ");

        int boypos = 1;
        int boycount = 0;
        int boysum = 0;

        int girlpos = 3;        
        int girlcount = 0;      
        int girlsum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            if (i == boypos) {
                boycount++;
                boysum += Integer.valueOf(words[i]).intValue();
                boypos += 4;
            }
            if (i == girlpos) {
                girlcount++;
                girlsum += Integer.valueOf(words[i]).intValue();
                girlpos += 4;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(boycount + " boys, " + girlcount + " girls");
        System.out.println("Boys sum = " + boysum);
        System.out.println("Girls sum = " + girlsum);

    }
}
```

The best solution that won't make your teacher suspicious....

Comment: brilliant mate, thank you so much, ill change it up since it has to involve files but this is a great template

Comment: i can post the other question that i had to help you with that reputation problem your having